# Android - Load properties file on application launch

Tags: android, properties, launch, android-context

Is there some part of the code that is always executed on application launch, regardless of the activity, where we have access to the context?

I need api keys for my application. I store them in a .properties file in asset, and access this file from `context.getRessources().getAssets()` every time I need to load them.

```
key = getKey(getContext())
```

I'd like to have a static variable storing them once they have been succesfully accessed once. But since I don't know when they will be accessed for the first time, I need to do something like

```
if(isKeySet()){
    key = getKey();
} else {
    setKey(getContext());
}
```

Which is not ideal, since I still have to pass a context. If I could make sure one part of the code is always executed (with access to the context), I could load them here and every subsequent call

```
key = getKey();
```

Comment: put the keys into the xml file loaded by SharedPreference static and load that in your Main Activity. Prefs should be addressable whereever needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Android [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class. It extends Context and is a base class to store the global application state.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    private static MyApplication mSingleton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        mSingleton = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mSingleton;
    }
}
```

In `androidManifest.xml`, you need to add `android:name="com.X.Y.Z.MyApplication"` in `<application>`

Now when your app launch, it will launch `MyApplication.onCreate` method.

After the call to `super.onCreate()`, you have access to `getApplicationContext()` and can initialise your singleton.

Comment: Some questions regarding this. I would make my KeyManager extends Application, and Call new KeyManager().getKey() to key the key.   |   GetKey would check is mSingleton is !null, return it, or else init it with it's context   |   And when the KeyManager I created in another activity is garbage collected, the mSingleton will retain it's value? (assuming it's static)   |   Is this scenario right, or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: No. You would call `KeyManager.getInstance().getKey()`. There would be only one object `mSingleton`. It would not be garbage collected because it is static.